# What is the minimum version for liblgrp support on Solaris

Tags: solaris

What is the minimum version of Solaris SunOS that supports liblgrp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is [documented](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19683-01/817-0713/6mggblq4k/index.html) in [Solaris 9](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19683-01/index.html)
but [not](http://search.oracle.com/search/search?group=Documentation&q=liblgrp+url:/docs/cd/E19455-01) in [Solaris 8](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19455-01/index.html).

Comment: thanks, also thanks for the links.  It's been a real pain for me to find the documentation since none of the google links to the old http://docs.sun.com get redirected.